# Edit multiple text value simultaneously

Tags: text-object

Edit multiple text value simultaneously

I’ve been using Blender since around 2012 and never have I came across a situation where I needed to use the text feature in blender to save you the confusion my problem is this. I need to be able to edit multiple text simultaneously so if I were to make a text and duplicate it 10 times I would like to be able to tap into edit mode and edit each text value simultaneously I’m to a point where I need to edit right around 500 different texts and I have to do these individually it’s becoming painstakingly difficult is there a way I can do this and add on I can use

Answer (score 3):

Select your Text and use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to create Duplicate Linked instead of **shift + D**

[image]

Just a small addition to this.

If you don't want to make the Duplicates again because you already have your objects, you could select the ones that you want them to be the same at the same time and use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> > Link Object Data.