# Applying an edit of an object to its duplicates

Tags: modeling, vertices

Is it possible to edit a set of vertices on an object, like moving them up and down, and apply that edit to its duplicates?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, if duplicated using Alt+D.

Comment: As @lemon said, when you duplicate an object with Alt+D instead of Shift+D, you have a **linked duplicate**. Changing the mesh on any of the linked duplicates changes the other meshes, too. If you already have made duplicates with Shift+D so that they are not linked, select all duplicates and at last the object with the changes, then hit Ctrl+L > _Link/Transfer Data_ > _Link Object Data_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit multiple text value simultaneously](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273060/edit-multiple-text-value-simultaneously)