# Is there any function in Blender 3.0 to convert meshes into instances and not lose the animation keys?

Tags: objects, instances

I'm pretty new in this program, was doing my university project, and I'm making a little city, so i duplicated A LOT of buildings and trees and now blender works very very slow (its 10GB file). I recently found out that there is an opportunity to duplicate meshes without copying it as object(instances), but I'm already made half of the project. Is it possible, to convert all my meshes (or mb some part at least) and save it's transform and keys? Blender version is 3.0
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you want linked duplications? In that case select your object(s), shift select the one you want to copy the mesh from, and press Ctrl L > Link Object Data

Comment: @moonboots I want to make blender work faster, i thought it could be possible, if I will turn all same objects into instances, what's difference between linked duplications and instances?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl L? Because it may be what you need, if you use linked duplications (Alt D instead of Shift D or Ctrl L > Link Object Data as explained) the objects will share the same mesh, it will make your file lighter

Comment: @moonboots That was really nice! Thank you! How can I mark your answer as right? I'm pretty new at this site too, maybe somebody will need this too...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273060/edit-multiple-text-value-simultaneously/273061#273061

Answer (score 1):

Use linked duplications. When you duplicate your object, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, this way your copy will share the exact same mesh and it will make your file lighter.

If you've already duplicate your objects but you want them to share the same mesh, select them all, shift select the one that has the mesh you want them to be linked to and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Object Data*.

Now if you edit the mesh of one of these objects, all the other ones will be modified as well.